# Brave Browser not showing ads

Tags: notification, 20.10, brave

I just started using Ubuntu 20.10 a few days ago.  I have been browsing with the Brave Browser
and have been very active.  Yet, I have not received a single ad yet.  Is anyone having this problem?  I have seen workarounds that involve deleting certain json files and restarting but this does not seem to work.

Update: Brave has an adblocker, but forwards its own ads to your notifications which you get paid for.

[image: Picture of Browser]

Comment: Is this some kind of a joke I'm too adblocker to understand?

Comment: Oh, you get _paid_ somehow to let ads display in Brave? If yes, I think it would be beneficial to update the question's text with this info; just to avoid this distraction I fell victim of :)

Comment: No ads? I'd call that a feature, not a bug.

Comment: I fixed this by reinstalling using the instructions from the brave website.  I installed the beta version and now I am seeing ads again.